# How to transition from one controller 1 to controller 2, and then have controller 2 immediately push another controller?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have a `MenuViewController` and a `UINavigationController` sitting inside a *ViewDeck*, a framework for a side menu. You simply initiate like so:

```
ListingViewController* lvc = [[ListingViewController alloc] init]; 
UINavigationController* homeNavStack = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:lvc];
MenuViewController* sideMenu = [[MenuViewController alloc] init]; 
IIViewDeckController* slideController = [[IIViewDeckController alloc] initWithCenterViewController:homeNavStack leftViewController:sideMenu];
```

Where the center view controller is my navigation controller, and the menu view controller is hidden on the left, and you must slide to the left to make it visible (similar to facebook's side menu).

There is a button in the side menu, that when pressed, needs to transition the app back to the navigation controller, and have it push a new view controller. Here is my code for this, inside `MenuViewController.m`:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if(indexPath.row == 0){
        NSLog(@"check"); 
        UserProfileViewController* userProfile = [[UserProfileViewController alloc] init];
        [self.viewDeckController toggleLeftViewAnimated:YES];
        [self.centerViewController pushViewController:userProfile animated:YES]; 
    }
}
```

`toggleLeftViewAnimated` brings back the center view controller, hiding the side menu again. I have given the side menu a reference to the center view controller, and using this, I ask it to push a new view controller. However when this method is called, nothing happens after the center view controller comes back into view. Does anyone know why this won't work?

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the self.centerViewController is a Navigation Controller instance that you have added as center view controller. You need to get the instance of Navigation Controller you have added in to the IIViewDeckController where now you are using self (which might be the MenuViewController). I think you need to write a method to get the navigation controller form the IIViewDeckController and after that pushing your userProfile will work perfectly.